# Automate refresh of large MySQL table on shared hosting (avoid max_allowed_packet error)

Tags: mysql, shared-hosting

I need to regularly replace a large MySQL table on my website. So I wrote a PHP script to do this....

- export table from local server into a .SQL file (contains CREATE TABLE and INSERTs)
- zip it up
- ftp it to remote host

And on the remote host run another script to ....

- unzip it
- import table into MySQL database

I.e. to import table I run ...

```
. . .
$queryStg = file_get_contents($sqlFilename);
$sqlQuery = mysqli_multi_query($mysqliLink, $queryStg);
. . .
```

But I get the error message ...

```
Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

I'm on shared hosting (goDaddy) so I cant fiddle with things like my.cfg or run mysql commands from SSH

Is there a way round this. E.g. is there some command that splits up the import into smaller batches or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Barmar. I gave it a go but it seems goDaddy dont allow `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`

Comment: Read the file a line at a time with `fgets()`, accumulating them into a string until it gets close to `max_allowed_packet`, then submit them as a multi-query. Repeat this until you're done.

Comment: @Barmat Great idea. That worked. (Had to remove the 'create table etc' stuff from the mysqldump as couldnt figure out how to get this on one line.)